# logstash replace @timestamp with logfile timestamp

Tags: logstash

Below is the timestamp in my logfiles which exist in my s3 bucket.

[2019-10-17 10:23:02.021 GMT] ***** ImpEx process 'CQExport'  FINISHED (status: OK  Details:  error=OK, id: 1571307782013). *****

[2019-11-27 00:15:01.799 GMT] DEBUG []Starting DR Backup

I want to replace logfile timestamp with @timestamp on kibana dashboard.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHtY9.png)

Ex: i want to replace/visualise Time Dec 16, 2019 @20:04:57.524 with logfile timestamp [2019-10-17 14:21:05.301 GMT] on kibana dashboard

Below is my snippet i have configured but unable to see logfile timestamp.

```
**filter {
      grok {
          match => { "message" => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}" }
      }
     date {
         match => [ "timestamp" , "ISO8601" ]
         target => "@logtimestamp"
         locale => "en"
         timezone => "UTC"
    }
}**
```

Comment: What is exactly the question? I don't see any.

Comment: Your grok pattern is wrong. Use this one instead: `^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]`

Answer (score 0):

Try below conf, where target is @timestamp

```
filter {
  grok {
            match => { "message" => "\[(?<timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}) (?<TZ>GMT)\]" }
        }
    date {
         match => [ "timestamp" , "ISO8601" ]
         target => "@timestamp"
         locale => "en"
         timezone => "UTC"
    }
}
```

Comment: sure Angel let me try

Comment: Angel still i am getting today date

Comment: Angel H still i am getting today date for @timestamp not replacing with logfile timestamp

Comment: try by changing the target =>"@logtimestamp" to target=>"@timestamp"

Answer (score 0):

What **Time Filter field name** did you choose when creating your index ?